# C# Iterative loop to run a DataGrieView rows - Index was out of range

Tags: c#, datagridview

Alright guys , 
I use a loop to run through the rows of a datagirdview in order to change the length of some values . 
The problem shown is  : "Index is out of range , must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Paramater name. Index."

```
for (k=1; k<=(dataGridView3.Rows.Count); k++)
                    {
                        string ChangeNumber = dataGridView3[k, 6].ToString();
                         ChangeNumber = ChangeNumber.Remove(ChangeNumber.Length - 2);
                        dataGridView3.Rows[k].Cells[6].Value = ChangeNumber;
                    }
```

my datagridview is DataGridView3 and I want my 6th column to have 2 less digits in the end. So I run this iteration for the cells of all rows in the 6th column. Any ideas ?

Edited : Added the whole exception form ! [image]

Ok this actually works ... !!!!

```
for (counter = 0; counter < (dataGridView3.Rows.Count); counter++)
                    {
                        string ChangeNumber = dataGridView3.Rows[counter].Cells["Value"].Value.ToString();
                        ChangeNumber = ChangeNumber.Remove(ChangeNumber.Length - 2);
                        dataGridView3.Rows[counter].Cells["Value"].Value = ChangeNumber;
                    }
```

It reduces the 2 digits that i needed but I still get an exception : 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: If the column is 6th, it's index is 5, since C# arrays are 0 based.

Comment: Is this code meant to be doing significant-figures / decimal places formatting? If so you should look at `DefaultCellStyle.Format` property of datagrid columns

Comment: I switched it to 5 which actualy makes sense but now I get a system exception '"DataGridViewTextBoxCell {columnindex=0 rowindex=5 is not a valid value for double. ' This appears 5 times and then I still get the first index error. The 6th column has numbers red from a csv file. The file has them in a 60.00 form but putting them into the grid the value becomes 6000 so I want to delete the last 2 digits of every cell in the 6th column. I don't mind hard coding it .

Comment: I also tried this iteration which gives me the exact same exception . 'foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView3.Rows)
                        {
                            string ChangeNumber = dataGridView3[k, 5].ToString();
                            ChangeNumber = ChangeNumber.Remove(ChangeNumber.Length - 2);
                            dataGridView3.Rows[k].Cells[5].Value = ChangeNumber;
                            k++;
                        }'

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I'm going to respond to both your question and comment here:

Question: I would recommend using `foreach(Row r in dataGridView3.Rows)`. This is an easy way to iterate through a list without having to check for null reference exception. I have made an assumption that a Row is a class here. If it is actually something like a double array then you just need to do `foreach(double[] d in dataGridView3.Rows)`.

Comment: As far as truncating the last two numbers off of your 6000, you can do it by doing `Int.Parse(varHoldingSixThousand.ToString().Replace(000, 0));`.

Let me know if anything doesn't make sense.

Edit: `foreach(DataGridViewRow d in dataGridView3.Rows)`

As far as truncating exactly two digits off the end of your number, you can use something a little more adaptable like: `int.Parse(varHoldingNumber.ToString().Substring(varHoldingNumber.ToString().Length - 2, 2))`

Comment: 6000 was just an example the numbers are differend . Can be 300 (which really should be 3) or 20000 (which really should be 200) . I just used foreach iteration method and gives me the same exception .

Comment: I haven't used any double arrays and Row is not a class .

Comment: There is a class for data grid view rows [as seen here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow(v=vs.110).aspx). I will edit answer with other info

Comment: Still same problem with the Edited version.

Comment: Can you post the exact null exception you are receiving?

Comment: Edited in the question screenshot the whole exception window. Too much text

Comment: Since you changed to foreach, did you start using k=0; before the loop begins? Because in your for loop, you're starting at k=1; which is incorrect, as you'll be skipping the first index (k=0;)